# Why bind does nothing while lambda works

Tags: c++, c++11

I asked the initial question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879120/can-i-use-stream-operator-with-bind). Now I have a follow-on question. Here is the code:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
using namespace std;

struct MyType {};
struct MyType2 {};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const MyType &n)
{
    cout << "MyType" << endl;
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const MyType2 &n)
{
    cout << "MyType2" << endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyType> vec;
    MyType mt;
    vec.push_back(mt);

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const MyType &mt) {cout << mt;});  // this works
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind((ostream&(ostream&, const MyType&))::operator<<, std::ref(std::cout), _1));  // this does nothing !

    return 0;
}
```

Do you see why that lambda works while that bind implementation does nothing? It compiles, but does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is invalid, you need to cast to a reference

```
static_cast<ostream&(&)(ostream&, const MyType&)>(::operator<<)
```

or to a pointer

```
static_cast<ostream&(*)(ostream&, const MyType&)>(&::operator<<)
```

Both will work with `std::bind`.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcb4f40944e35e35)

Note that your original code is rejected by Coliru's GCC 4.8.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile on gcc-4.8, it complains about an invalid cast to function type. clang does compile the code, but does nothing, not sure what's going on there. Anyway, you must cast to function pointer type, not function type.

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind((ostream&(*)(ostream&, const MyType&))::operator<<, std::ref(std::cout), _1));
//                                                       ^^^
```

Or better yet, lose the C-style cast and use `static_cast` instead

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
              std::bind(static_cast<ostream&(*)(ostream&, const MyType&)>(::operator<<), std::ref(std::cout), _1));
```